# How can i choose one of the many string and show all possible outcome?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to generate all the possible strings. However, I need to choose one string or the other string or maybe even the 3rd string. I don't know how we can generate to pick either BU, AU , or A or B or C
For example:

BU / AU / AC  , A / B / C

```
Result can be:
BU A
BU B
BU C
AU A
AU B 
AU C
etc...
```

Comment: So, you wanna generate _combinations_ of these strings.

Comment: yea but it has to read in "/" as option 1, option 2 and etc    and the "," as the next part of the string

Comment: this is called 'combinations of strings'.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping I understand what you want (be more specific in future):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
        std::string s1[3] = {"A", "B", "C"};
        std::string s2[3] = {"Z", "Y", "X"};

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++)
        {
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 3; i2++)
                {
                        std::cout << s1[i1] << " / " << s2[i2];
                        if ((i1 < 2) || (i2 < 2))
                        {
                                std::cout << ", ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                std::cout << std::endl;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
A / Z, A / Y, A / X, B / Z, B / Y, B / X, C / Z, C / Y, C / X
```